# GetBsic() in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I need help in fetching `getbsic()` function

I am completely Neophyte(New) to android 
But yes can create activity assign button pass intent create db etc;..
Have been trying to call `phonstateListner` and `cellidentityGsm` but not getting how to show on activity.

Comment: I think it sounds like you might be better off going over general tutorials.

Comment: Yes have gone through general tutorial on developer.android.com but am not getting how to implement or getbsic()